# Approaches to create something like play games genre filter

Tags: android, xml

What is the approaches to create something similar to this

[image: Ex]

Let's say i want to foucs on only one group like that Trending and New one, When choosing one of them the selected item back ground being changes. If you click again on that item it returns to it's normal state.

**Edit**

To give more clarification, what i need to do is exactly the same as this design.

You have few options in that list let's say for example the colors example (red,green blue,yellow).

What i need to achieve is when the user click for example (red) two things happens, first the background changes (meaning that this button had been selected) and second a toast appears with all the selected colors in this case (red).

If the user clicks the red button again then the background back to original.

If the red still pressed and the green button clicked the background for the green button changes and a toast with all selected colors appear in our case (red , green).

Another feature which is the circle button with X appears after you choose any button to reset the selection state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a drawable with selector as its root element, with different states for pressed/selected. You could also toggle the buttons background color in its onClickListener

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"
     android:text="Hello" />
```

```
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

    </selector>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will also wait other to give more explanation.